# How to analyze source code by pygments(using pygount) and get a SUM

Tags: python, pygments

Using `pygount` I am trying to get the SUM of: Codes, Comments and Empty. I do **not** have any errors but I think I messed my relative paths.

Firstly check the tree below for a visualization

```
C:\...\Projects\TestProject
├───utils
│   ├───__init__.py 
│   └───loc.py
└───launcher.py
```

`ROOT_DIR` const def is inside `__init__` of util folder. I am not sure if my relative path should have 1x or 2x `.parent` to reach "TestProject"(which is the root dir).

```py
from pathlib import Path
from .loc import test

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

Below is the the `.loc` file

```py
from utils import ROOT_DIR

class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.code = 0
        self.docs = 0
        self.empty = 0

    def count(self):
        for subdir, _, files in os.walk(ROOT_DIR / "TestProject"):
            for file in (f for f in files if f.endswith(".py")):
                analysis = SourceAnalysis.from_file(f"{subdir}/{file}", "pygount", encoding="utf-8")
                self.code += analysis.code_count
                self.docs += analysis.documentation_count
                self.empty += analysis.empty_count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.path.join instead of /

Comment: Why would you do that? `pathlib.Path` with `/` is a convenient, clear, modern, built-in way of constructing filesystem paths.